# Updating ubuntu 18.04 broke ingame fonts (terraria)

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, updates

Today I did apt-get update and apt-get upgrade on my Ubuntu 18.04 and it broke Terraria.

Let me give some more of the backstory - Some time ago I installed a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 and everything seemed to be fine untill I tried to play some games. Both Terraria and Don't Starve were broken. Being hotheaded I decided to switch to PopOS but it was the same problem.
After that, I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 and everything worked perfectly. Untill today.
After doing update and upgrade my game is broken again.

The console said the following things are going to be upgraded:
libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04

The small (as in on screen size) ingame fonts are completely broken. How do I fix this?
Attached are screenshots of the problems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8he5Q.jpg

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

What I did to fix this issue was run steam in the beta version

steam > Settings > Account > beta participation

then allow steam play for all titles

Steam > Settings > Steam play > Advanced > Enable steam play for all other titles

Then restart and it should work !